# Exporting global const variable from a DLL

Tags: c++, qt, dll

The following is a simplified version of the code I am using with the Qt framework:

foo.h:

```
// Defines DLL import or export as required
#if defined(REGEXUTIL_LIBRARY)
  #define LIBRARY_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
  #define LIBRARY_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

LIBRARY_EXPORT extern const QString testString;
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"
LIBRARY_EXPORT const QString testString = "Test string";
```

test.cpp, in module which imports this DLL:

```
const QString s = testString;
```

I know both the DLL and the test compile and link correctly since the above works with a non-const QString. However, when I make the QString const I get an unresolved external symbol error upon compiling the test, which I am assuming is to do with the fact that the const variable is not initialised in the header file. If I do initialise it there, I get errors about the DLL import prefix not being allowed when I attempt to compile the test.

What is the correct way to fix this error? I want to be able to access the const QString variables from modules which import this DLL.

Comment: Have you tried without the 'extern' keyword?

Comment: If I get rid of extern then the DLL errors on compile with "testString is already defined in foo.obj".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If solution of const string being defined in header is acceptable to you, there is no need to import the symbol at all:

```
//foo.h
static const QString testString = "Test string";
```

should be enough - testString can be accessed both in modules importing the dll and inside the dll itself.

Comment: Would this mean there would be multiple define errors if this header were included in lots of different files?

Comment: @x6herbius No, because it is defined as static.

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice that. Should theoretically work, I'll just test it now.

Comment: This will use the constant throughout the program regardless of what value that constant has in the DLL, which may be updated without the program knowing about this. I.e. eventually you'll get different values in the DLL and in the program.